# What does dollar signs do in manifest.mf class-path?

Tags: java, spring-boot, websphere-liberty, manifest.mf, hk2

I have a Spring Boot project using Jersey. spring-jersey3 has a dependency to HK2:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
    <artifactId>hk2</artifactId>
    <version>${hk2.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

The HK2's manifest Class-Path looks like this:

```
Class-Path: $hk2-utils.$jar $javax.inject.$jar $hk2-api.$jar $aopallia
 nce-repackaged.$jar $config-types.$jar $hk2-core.$jar $hk2-config.$ja
 r $tiger-types.$jar $hibernate-validator.$jar $validation-api.$jar $j
 boss-logging.$jar $classmate.$jar $hk2-locator.$jar $javax.inject.$ja
 r $javassist.$jar $hk2-runlevel.$jar $class-model.$jar $asm-all-repac
 kaged.$jar
```

When I deploy this project as a war on Liberty Profile, then I receive a lot of error messages regarding HK2's manifest file. I get one error like this for each jar file in the Class-Path in HK2's manifest file:

```
The manifest class path $hk2-utils.$jar can not be found in jar file wsjar:file:<path to WLP server>/usr/servers/int/dropins/<name of application>.war!/WEB-INF/lib/hk2-2.5.0-b32.jar or its parent.
```

The hk2-2.5.0-b32.jar does not contain any jar-libraries, but all the libraries on the HK2's classpath does exist in the lib folder of the application.

So my question is: **What do theese dollar signs in the manifest Class-Path mean? And is it possible that this syntax is what makes my Liberty Profile server complain?**

Comment: That just looks like a bug to me

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue in the hk2 code base.  See:

[Fix for Manifest Class Path](https://github.com/hk2-project/hk2/commit/f9283da566104511b4d137eb78fe83fc3c79c08d)

Comment: But how is the manifest class path generated? We can see that the manifest class path points to files with names like: hk2-utils.jar, but our lib folder contains the same file with filename: hk2-utils-2.5.0-b32.jar. All jars have the version postfix. When i manually change the manifest class path to point to hk2-utils-2.5.0-b32.jar instead, then the WLP log stops complaining about that file.

Comment: We do use a custom classpath in the maven file to remove the version numbers.  I'm not sure what standard practice is with regards to this